# MySQL Stored Procedure check if array parameter set

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to check if an stored proc input is

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `driver_journey_ids`(
    IN p_driverID VARCHAR(255), # driver ids
    IN p_vehicleID VARCHAR(255), # vehicle ids
)
SELECT
    pl.eventID
FROM payload AS pl
WHERE 
    CASE 
        WHEN p_driverID IS NOT NULL THEN pl._driverID IN (p_driverID)
        ELSE TRUE
    END 
    AND CASE 
        WHEN p_vehicleID IS NOT NULL THEN pl._vehicleID IN (p_vehicleID)
        ELSE TRUE
    END
```

> CALL driver_journey_ids("123,124,125",null)

The SP is something like this, but the WHEN is causing an issue.
Is there a way to check if an array has a value? 
It works if a single value is passed in the call, but not if more than one is passed in the same parameter.

Cheers,
Phil

Comment: Looks like you need [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: You are also missing 'AND' between the CASE statements

Comment: FIND_IN_SET requires 2 params, and if either is NULL then it returns 0 or NULL if one of them isnt set. The issue there is, I only want to check if p_driverID contains a value (not a specific value, just anything other than NULL), if I pass in a param say FIND_IN_SET('1',p_driverID) and p_driverID contains "23,25" then it will return 0, and not add the where clause. (but it needs to, as the parameter isnt empty)